# Is there a library to use twilio-conversations in React Native?

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

I've been researching how I can do App-Chat with twilio-conversations in react native, but I haven't found anything that can help me.

Comment: Did my answer bring you further in your attempt to integrate `twilio-conversations` in your React Native app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I have been told by the Conversations team that the Conversations JS SDK has been tested with React Native and is the recommended approach for using Conversations in React Native.

This is the approach taken in the [Twilio Frontline](https://www.twilio.com/frontline) app.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio usually provides both JavaScript and IOS/Android SDKs. But when talking React Native there is no direct support from Twilio as far as I know. You can try to use the [JavaScript SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/sdk-download-install) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@twilio/conversations)) but I doubt you'll be successful as it probably relies on the browser API. Your best bet is probably to have a look at the [TwilioChatJsReactNative](https://github.com/twilio/TwilioChatJsReactNative) example which uses [twilio-chat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-chat) (it's linked on the [Demo / Reference Client Applications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/sdk-download-install#demo-reference-client-applications) section of the Programmable Chat Client SDKs). That has the downside that Programmable Chat support will run out mid-2022.